# How is Xcode able to skirt GPL?

Tags: xcode

Xcode is built over gcc, which is GPLed, and so any product built on gcc should also be released under the GPL.

How is Apple able to avoid releasing Xcode's source code?

Answer (score 3):

Any product built on GCC's *code* needs to be GPLed.  GCC is a separate program, and is replaceable with another compiler such as icc or clang, so the IDE itself isn't bound by the GPL.

Comment: I see. Legalities of programming are not welcome. Thanks for your hint, cHao.

Comment: Yeah...on SO, we tend to talk about the code itself, and leave the legal stuff to lawyers.  http://programmers.stackexchange.com *might* be able to help more, but something tells me it'd be off topic there too.